# How do I convert frequency to data capacity?

Tags: frequency

So I am completing my assignment and I am stuck on only this question:

**For the voice communication in task 2, it has been decided that a 16-QAM (2 phase shifts and 8
amplitude levels) will be used. If the maximum frequency for this voice circuit is the frequency
calculated for Task 2, then what is the data capacity of the analog line, assuming ideal conditions
(no noise)?**

I found the frequency of Task 2 to be 10 MHz. I am not sure how to use this information to convert it into some form of bit rate.

Please help if possible.

Comment: How many bits per symbol? How many symbols per second?

Answer (score 1):

Not one to usually use this site, but I think we are in the same class and I stumbled upon your question with a google search. 
If you check out this http://home.ubalt.edu/abento/650/physicaldlink/sld032.htm 
then you should get a bit closer to the answer. 
Tip- think of s as frequency with the formula b = s x n

Comment: We would prefer to have the relevant parts quoted here.  Links to external sites will eventually fail.

Comment: `b = s x n` n is reference of what , the link are not clear do they mean multiply symbol on frequency in MHz